# How to use 'node-7z' on Windows?

Tags: node.js, windows, 7zip

I am trying to set up an Azure webjob which unzips files passed to it. I am using an npm package `node-7z` to achieve this but I am having trouble getting it to work on windows machine. Apparently, adding a 7z.exe file on the same level as the package.json should work but it doesn't seem to do the trick. If anybody has managed to configure node-7z for windows setup, could you please advise on how to resolve this matter.

Comment: According to the [README](https://github.com/quentinrossetti/node-7z), the executable either needs to be on the system PATH or in the same directory as your `package.json`.

Comment: @JoeClay I downloaded the 7z.exe and put it on the same level as package.json but no cigar. Just not sure how to run it.

Answer (score 2):

I know this is an old post, but I am doing work with **node-7z**. For you or anyone wondering about this.

You specify a string path of the exec, as bin in options object, I have not had the chance to test this.

**`$bin`**  string  Path to another 7-Zip binary. Default: 7z

Reference from here : [node7z Github readme](https://github.com/quentinrossetti/node-7z#installation)

`const myStream = Seven.add('File.7z', 'File.txt',{
   $bin: pathTo7zip
})`

Comment: There is `7zip-bin` package available having path of binary. Refer https://github.com/quentinrossetti/node-7z#installation